# Name / Adapter for Vintage AC Plug

Tags: ac, connector, high-voltage, adapter, plug

I just came into possession of a bunch of vintage "audio" gear from the nuclear labs at Los Alamos (a bunch of test oscillators, oscilloscopes, pulse generators, etc). Been checking it out, seeing what works, etc.

A lot of the stuff has a weird AC input that looks like the picture below. Any idea what this connector type is called, and where I might be able to find an adapter to a modern plug?

[image]

Comment: An old "business machine" power cord connector?  Looks like what was on the old electromechanical adding machines and typewriters.

Answer (score 3):

After some further research I've found out this connector is called a PH-163.

You can find them here: https://marvac.com/products/vintage-switchcraft-lac3gd-ph-163-oval-type-hp-connector-3-pin-round-ac3g

Adapters look like this: [https://www.amazon.com/Vintage-Oval-Hewlett-Packard-Power/dp/B011CAFIGC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B011CAFIGC)